# Problem with using grep command with env variable containing special characters

Tags: grep, ksh

I have a variable "abc" with value  "xyz*!@#" in my unix account (`ksh`). I used `export` command to export this variable into the environment.
When I use `grep` command as below

```
env |grep xyz
```

I get the output

```
abc=xyz*!@#
```

But when I use the following command

```
env | grep xyz*!
```

As expected I don't get the output as

```
abc=xyz*!@#
```

In fact, I don't get any output at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` has special meaning in regular expressions, so escape it:

```
env | grep 'xyz\*!'
```

Or use the `-F` option to tell `grep` to treat the parameter as plain text, not as regular expression:

```
env | grep -F 'xyz*!'
```

Comment: When not using regex, `grep -F` is probably easier than trying to escape not-a-regex into a regex with normal `grep`.